# "I better not ask," vs "I had better not ask."

Tags: expressions, idioms

Example:

> Speaker A: Thanks for the fish, I'll feed it to my crocodile.
>
> Speaker B: Your crocodile? I (had) better not ask.

*I better not ask* sounds better to me ([2,480](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1177&bih=856&tbm=bks&q=%22I%20better%20not%20ask%22&oq=%22I%20better%20not%20ask%22&gs_l=serp.3...58286.58434.0.58519.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..2.0.0.4kX906tR4Nw) results on Google Books). However, the one with the most results is *I had better not ask* ([23,1000](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1177&bih=856&tbm=bks&q=%22I%20had%20better%20not%20ask%22&spell=1&sa=X&ei=mghKVc3KIYS3mwWWhIDYAw&ved=0CBoQBSgA&dpr=1)).

Which one is the most common idiom? (I'm open to other suggestions.)

Comment: When people say what sounds like "I better not ask" they are usually saying "I'd better not ask".

Comment: @Hot Licks So the *'d* is actually a *had*?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @HotLicks I see, thanks. It sounded weird to me. Because *had* makes it sound as if it was happening in the past.

Comment: Don't ask me to give you the part of speech of "had" in that case -- it's been almost 50 years since I studied this stuff.  But it doesn't mean "in the past".  (I'm thinking maybe it's subjunctive mood, but that's just a guess.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Michael Swan's Modern English usage - p 230.

> We use had better to give strong advice, or to tell people what to do
>   (including ourselves)

- It's seven o'clock. I'd better put the meat in the oven.

> Had better refers to the immediate future, but **the form is always past**
>   (*have better is impossible*). After had better we *use the infinitive without to*.

- It's late - you had better hurry up.

> Had better is not used in polite requests.

*Compare:*

1. Could you help me, if you've got time? (request)
2. **You'd** better help me. lf you don't, there'll be trouble.
   (order/threat)

Note that had better does not usually suggest that the action recommended
would be better than another one that is being considered - there is no idea of
comparison. ***The structure means 'It would be good to .. :, not 'It would be
better to .. .***'.

> **Had is sometimes dropped in very informal speech.**
>
> 1. You better go now.
> 2. I better try again later.

Comment: The structure shows a preference for something. Your last sentence is incorrect. "I'd better go" ~= "My going is better than my staying".